# Write a program to compute the sum of all divisors of positive integer input n. Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

Write a program to compute the sum of all divisors of positive integer input n.
input example: a positive integer 10
output:1+2+5+10=18

```
def factor(n): if n==0: return[0] if n<=3: return[1] x=n list=[1] i=2 while i<=x: if x%i==0: if i !=list[-1]: list.append(i) x=x//i i=2 continue i+=1
```

Comment: Please provide your solution first so that we can contribute and help.

Comment: def factor(n):
    if n==0:
        return[0]
    if n<=3:
        return[1]
    x=n
    list=[1]
    i=2
    while i<=x:
        if x%i==0:
            if i !=list[-1]:
                list.append(i)
                x=x//i
                i=2
                continue
        i+=1

Comment: Please write in the question section with proper format so that anyone can follow easily. Thanks.

Comment: Add the code in the question and mention the error you are facing along with sample input and expected and actual output

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to write it with the proper format, I had tried, but not successed.

Comment: I want to input the integer is 36 then output 91

Comment: @余东霖, just edit the question and add the code. If formatting is not correct, some one will do it for you.

Comment: @Saurav Rai     thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
n=int(input("Enter an integer:"))
print("The sum of all divisors of given positive integer input is:")
sum = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if(n%i==0):
        sum = sum + i
print(sum)

Enter an integer:36
The sum of all divisors of given positive integer input is:                                                             
91
```

Hope this will be of your help.

Comment: def allFactor(n):      
     if n == 0:
         return [0]
     if n == 1:
         return [1]
     rlist = []
     i = 1
     while i <= n:
         if n % i == 0:
             rlist.append(i)
             n = n // i
             i = 2
         i += 1
     return rlist
 print(allFactor(36))

Comment: @余东霖 You can write the solution as provided above. Much simpler to understand.